# how to add bloc in the top of columns.yaml

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

**I am new to octobercms**,i am trying to create a know plugin to add a statistics in the top of all my **columns.yaml**, how can I do that without add a htm bloc in all my columns list 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpLFa.png)

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do? You're trying to display your plugin on the top of ALL the possible list renderers of all loaded possible plugin that use the backend listrenderer?

Comment: i try de display the statistic plugin in the list page ( if ther is a configuration for this model ) my problem i have to add this bloc dynamicly not to add a code in all my list ( take a look at the image )

Comment: It's difficult to discuss a solution without first understanding the problem. Please, explain the problem itself and not the solution that you have in mind. For more info on presenting your problem see !help. Thanks! Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: oki i sorry , i just try to link my plugin result and display them in the list page ( in the toolbar list ) without add htm code in all the columns.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/extending#extending-backend-list

You can extend the columns, you can extend the fields, etc.. a lot of it, but not the header. I also checked in the code, but there is no programmatical way to extend the header that's laid out in the documentation or code.

You need to find another way to interface with those classes or columns than the way you had tought out